# how can I solve Electron EACCES installation error under Docker?

Tags: docker, npm, installation, electron

I have a problem installing Electron in a docker container. Here is the log:

```
# npm ci --force --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated @braintree/sanitize-url@3.1.0: Potential XSS vulnerability patched in v6.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /workspaces/cassiopee/nghyd/node_modules/electron
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, stat '/root/.cache/electron/2b84ab10611c34771b1b29e2390eaa8b69e5185e5065252938d8eb00e4c17a3d/electron-v19.0.7-linux-x64.zip'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-07-11T09_36_51_171Z-debug-0.log
```

I originally install with `npm ci --force` and, as you can see, I tried a solution (`--unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`) proposed in many forums without success.
The Docker image is based on Debian Bullseye.

Thanks for the help.

Edit:
Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:bullseye

LABEL maintainer="xxx"

# base packages
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    locales \
    curl \
    build-essential \
    wget \
    git \
    rsync \
    net-tools iproute2 inetutils-ping sudo

# UTF-8 locale
RUN sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen \
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

# nodejs
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    nodejs

# python3
RUN apt-get install -y \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    python3-setuptools \
    && python3 -m pip install mkdocs python-markdown-math mkdocs-material

# chromium and procps (e2e)
RUN apt-get install -y chromium procps

# pandoc & LaTeX for PDF doc
RUN apt-get install -y \
    pandoc \
    texlive \
    latexmk \
    texlive-latex-extra \
    texlive-bibtex-extra

# wine
RUN wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key \
    && apt-key add winehq.key \
    && echo "deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ buster main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq.list \
    && dpkg --add-architecture i386 \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y software-properties-common apt-transport-https \
    && wget -nc https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/Debian_10/Release.key \
    && apt-key add Release.key \
    && add-apt-repository 'deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/Debian_10 ./' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --install-recommends winehq-stable

# java & Android SDK
ENV SDK_URL="https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6609375_latest.zip" \
    ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/android-sdk" \
    ANDROID_VERSION=28 \
    ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=28.0.3
RUN apt-add-repository 'deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    openjdk-8-jdk \
    gradle \
    && mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME" .android \
    && cd "$ANDROID_HOME" \
    && mkdir cmdline-tools \
    && cd cmdline-tools \
    && curl -o sdk.zip $SDK_URL \
    && unzip sdk.zip \
    && rm sdk.zip \
    && export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools/bin \
    && yes | sdkmanager --licenses \
    && $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update \
    && $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION}" \
    "platforms;android-${ANDROID_VERSION}" \
    "platform-tools" \
    && echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/" >> /root/.bashrc \
    && echo "export ANDROID_HOME=${ANDROID_HOME}" >> /root/.bashrc \
    && echo "export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=${ANDROID_HOME}" >> /root/.bashrc \
    && echo "export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools/bin" >> /root/.bashrc

WORKDIR /build
```

Excerpt of the package.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^14.0.0-beta.40",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.4",
    "@ngx-matomo/tracker": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/pako": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/sprintf-js": "^1.1.2",
    "angular2-chartjs": "^0.5.1",
    "angular2-hotkeys": "^13.1.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-zoom": "^0.7.7",
    "cordova-android": "^10.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^3.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.14",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^7.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^3.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.5",
    "core-js": "^3.23.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "he": "^1.2.0",
    "jalhyd": "file:../jalhyd",
    "katex": "^0.16.0",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "mathjax": "^3.2.2",
    "mermaid": "^8.8.0",
    "ngx-markdown": "^14.0.1",
    "ngx-material-file-input": "^4.0.0",
    "ngx-webstorage-service": "^5.0.0",
    "pako": "^2.0.4",
    "primeng": "^14.0.0-rc.1",
    "roboto-fontface": "^0.10.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.5",
    "screenfull": "^6.0.2",
    "svg-pan-zoom": "^3.6.1",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.0.4",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.11",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.30.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "^5.30.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.30.5",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova": "^11.0.0",
    "electron": "^19.0.7",
    "electron-builder": "^23.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "fs-extra": "^10.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.2.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.2",
    "typescript": "~4.7.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.3"
  },
```

Comment: As in, you're trying to `RUN npm ci` in your Dockerfile and getting this error?  Can you [edit] the question to include the complete Dockerfile and any other details for how you're setting up this environment?

Comment: >As in, you're trying to RUN npm ci in your Dockerfile and getting this error?

No, I'm in the container defined by the given Dockerfile (through VSCode) and run `npm ci ...` manually.

Comment: By the way, the file `stat` is complaining about (`/root/.cache/electron/2b84ab10611c34771b1b29e2390eaa8b69e5185e5065252938d8eb00e4c17a3d/electron-v19.0.7-linux-x64.zip`) does not exist. A problem in the creation of the parent directories ? (`electron` and `2b84...` do not exist either)

Comment: I tried to rebuild the underlying Docker image, install a previous Electron version (17.4.10), a recent npm update (8.13.2), no luck, same error message.

Comment: `npm install` outside the container (in the same filesystem, same directory so same package.json, npm 8.13.2) works.

Comment: I took a look at Electron installation files and found that `install.js` was refering to a `electron_config_cache` variable. So I tried `electron_config_cache=/tmp npm ci --force --unsafe-perm` and it works. Strange, because `/tmp` and `/root` are on the same mount point...

Comment: I tried to `chmod 777 /root/.cache` before running `npm ci --force --unsafe-perm`, no luck.

Comment: The solution I found was to not work as root in the container (add a user in Dockerfile). Then no need to run `npm ci...` forcing the Electron cache path.